# how to install lte acts-as-messageable for rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, gemfile

I want to implement messaging in my rails application and I found [`LTe` / `acts-as-messageable`](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable). Finally it directed me to a fork [`openfirmware` / `acts-as-messageable`](https://github.com/openfirmware/acts-as-messageable) for a version for Rails 2.

`openfirmware` / `acts-as-messageable` depends on `activerecord` 3 but my Rails 2.3.14 depends on `activerecord` 2.3.14.

How can I define my Gemfile so that I can install `openfirmware` / `acts-as-messageable` successfully? 
I installed both `activerecord` 2.3.14 and 3.0.11, but it does not work.

When I run 'bundle install' it showed:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:  

    acts-as-messageable (= 0.3.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activerecord (~> 3.0.0) x86-mingw32  

    rails (= 2.3.14) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activerecord (2.3.14)
```

My Gemfile:

```
gem "activerecord", ">= 2.3.14", "<= 3.0.11"
gem "rails", "2.3.14"
```

Please help.

Comment: You can't use a gem depend of active support 3 with a rail 2 application. Found another gem without this dependance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment - you can't use Rails 3 *and* rails 2 at the same time. The correct solution is to go find a Rails2 compliant version of ActsAsMessageable.

When you went to look at the fork - you were looking at the default "master" branch - which is rails3 compliant. but you can look at other "branches": one of which is named Rails2.3.11compatible, which seems promising :)

The link below goes to that fork:

https://github.com/openfirmware/acts-as-messageable/tree/rails2.3.11_compatible